# Python selenium: I need help finding elements within elements on Autotask.net

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find an element on the Autotask webpage in order to interact with it:

I'm using the following code to search within elements:

```
header=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html')
body=header.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
body1=body.find_element_by_css_selector('#WorkspaceContainer')
body1.find_element_by_css_selector('#WorkspaceContainer > div:nth-child(1)')
body2=body1.find_element_by_css_selector('#WorkspaceContainer > div:nth-child(1)')
body2.find_element_by_css_selector('#PageContainer')
body3=body2.find_element_by_css_selector('#PageContainer')
body3.find_element_by_css_selector('#PageContainerFrame')
body4=body3.find_element_by_css_selector('#PageContainerFrame')
body4.find_element_by_css_selector('html')
body5=body4.find_element_by_css_selector('html')
body5.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
body6=body5.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
```

It seemed like I was successfully navigating through them, but it fails at this line with the exception:

```
body4.find_element_by_css_selector('html')

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate    element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"html"}
```

I was using mouse movements and clicks via pyautogui module to interact with the site, but I've been told that interacting with the element itself is more reliable. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Is there an iframe that you'd like to find element inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you're trying to handle element inside an `iframe`.

To do this you need to switch to this frame at first:

```
body3.switch_to_frame('PageContainerFrame')
body3.find_element_by_css_selector('html')
```

P.S. If you need to handle just one element, you'd better to point on it directly with relative `XPath` instead of consecutive stepping from parent elements to child...

Comment: My xpath is id('Table6')/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[3]/x:a

Comment: Which element you want to handle? Is it a button or just a link? Describe it so I can search for it on page

Comment: The link text is a ticket number (i.e. T20161010.0100), it links to the ticket. Eventually, I'd like to use ActionChains to click on it. Once clicked, it should open another window with the ticket information.

Comment: You should use following lines: `driver.switch_to_frame('PageContainerFrame')` (suppose that `PageContainerFrame` is an `id` of `iframe` that contains target link) `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(., "T20161010.0100")]').click()`